# CMakeLists for Qt Widgets Application

Tags: qt, cmake

I have a simple Qt Widgets Application with project structure as follows

[image]

I want to build it with cmake and mingw
cmake 2.8.12
qt 5.2

How should my CMakeLists looks like ?

I'm trying with this ones, but have an error "recipe for target failed" when mingw make:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

project(testproject)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "D:\\Development\\qt\\5.2.1\\mingw48_32")

find_package(Qt5Widgets)

qt5_wrap_ui(uifiles mainwindow.ui)

add_executable(helloworld WIN32 mainwindow.cpp)

target_link_libraries(helloworld Qt5::Widgets)
```

Comment: Just to give you some doc, there's an official CMake manual for Qt5: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/cmake-manual.html